# Knowledge "Edit As Draft" button returning to published version

Tags: knowledge

I'm building a Knowledge implementation, and in one sandbox, whenever I click "Edit As Draft," I'm given a message that the current version will remain published. I confirm, and it does not redirect me - I stay on the Published version. To find the draft I made, I have to search for it.

In another sandbox, when I click "Edit As Draft," I get to edit the record, then I'm redirected to the new Draft version.

Is there a setting that determines what happens? The latter functionality is far preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The setting that you are looking for is "**Allow users to create and edit articles from the Articles tab (Classic Only)**"

[image]